# Extend leaflet with plugin on specific leaflet version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, leaflet

I'm using two different versions of Leaflet in the same project.

For this i installed the latest version of leaflet using an alias ("leaflet-latest").
After importing the library, i use the noConflict function to use both versions.

"L" keyword is used for an old version of Leaflet and "Leaflet" keyword is used for the latest version.

```
import L from "leaflet-latest";
import "leaflet-hotline";

var Leaflet = L.noConflict();

// L.hotline is defined
// Leaflet.hotline undefined (is not a function)
```

Everything is working well except when i want to use a plugin with the latest version.
Here, i wanted to use the "leaflet-hotline" plugin but when i import it, it extends the global variable L and not "Leaflet".

Any suggestions on how to extend Leaflet and not L?

I tried to solve the problem using this code but it's not a good approach.

```
import L from "leaflet-latest";
import "leaflet-latest/dist/leaflet.css";
import L_Hotline from "leaflet-hotline";

var Leaflet = L.noConflict();

Leaflet.hotline = L_Hotline.hotline;
```

In this case, the Leaflet hotline doesn't extends from the good library.

Comment: How do you import your old version of Leaflet?

Comment: Which build tool/bundler/framework do you use? Or do you use ES modules directly?

Comment: it's a react application created with create-react-app, so the bundler should be webpack. The old version is imported with a cdn in index.html file `<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

From the [docu](https://github.com/iosphere/Leaflet.hotline):

```
// Pass Leaflet to the plugin.
// Only required to overload once, subsequent overloads will return the same instance.
require('leaflet-hotline')(L);
```

So it should work like that:

```
import L from "leaflet-latest";
import "leaflet-latest/dist/leaflet.css";

var Leaflet = L.noConflict();
require('leaflet-hotline')(Leaflet);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It seems to be the solution but now i have this error `Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__(...) is not a function`